# The safe is not working after creating hashtag system for my Django project

Tags: python, django, django-views

I made a hashtag system for my Django project but after making it the safe isn't working and if a user wants to use special characters it shows weird in output.
Example I want to write:
"  Hello, I'm Ramin  "
it will show " Hello, I & #x27;m Ramin "

Can anyone help me?